# CodeIgniter - extend native library in multiple-site setup

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, native

I want to use a central CI setup for multiple sites. The way I handle this is I created a package called MPACK and added it to autoload in the config file of each site.

**Folder Structure:**

> /main
>
> > /system (CI 2 System folder)
> >
> > /MPACK
>
> /site1
>
> > /application
>
> site2
>
> > /application

Inside this MPACK I have share libraries, models, helpers, etc.

However, I would like to have an extended MY_Form_Validation that would be common to ALL sites. Adding the class file to /MPACK/libraries fails. Adding it to /site1/application works fine, as expected.

Is there any way to do this extending inside MPACK?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should just keep copies of the core classes you want to include in each of your application and have a separate folder for each project. Wouldn't it be easier to manage like the way I described?

Comment: I think it would be harder to manage because once I make a change / bug fix, I would have to replicate it to all sites. For example, if I built a search engine, I would have the search class in the MPACK and just extend it in each application based on different needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
// Placed your MY_Form_validation.php under MPACK/libraries
$this->load->add_package_path('/path/to/MPACK');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

You can get more information from [CodeIgniter User Guide - Loader Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html). :)

You can also autoload your package in `/application/config/autoload.php` : `$autoload['packages'] = array('/path/to/MPACK');`

**EDIT**: turn out that the above solution doesn't work, because Loader always look for APPPATH & BASEPATH first, and I not sure modifying this core class won't break something. Here is another solution in theory:

You should have your MPACK form validation lib, and sites' form validation lib should be symlinks to the MPACK one:

```
/site1/application/MY_Form_validation.php -> /MPACK/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

If you just use everything from MPACK, nothing specifically for /site1 or /site2, just make a folder link:

```
/site1/application/libraries/ -> /MPACK/application/libraries/
```

Hope this help =)

You can read more here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Multiple_Applications_via_Symlinks/

Comment: Hi Rocco, that doesn't work. It just loads the default form_validation class. Apparently Code Igniter doesn't check the packages for MY_ classes.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution. Will that slow down the loading if the site gets hundreds/thousands of hits per second?

Comment: Imo, it shouldn't be any performance issue unless you do somethink like `link_1 -> link_2 -> ... -> link_n -> actual_file`. Anyway, I think you should do some bench-marking =)